# PyCharm doesn't show me unresolved references in the editor

Tags: python, pycharm

I am very frustrated as I don't find a solution to this problem, because most of the questions you find searching this refer to having problems with pyCharm showing unresolved references when they should work, but for me it's the other way around, if I use references which should clealy be unresolved, pyCharm doesn't show me in the editor, I only get to know it when I run the file. I am using a venv.

[foofiii should be marked as unresolved reference, but it isn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26aII.png)

[Here you see it's producing an error when I click run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COz4O.png)

I have tried:

- setting my Project interpreter to a different one
- marking my project as sources root
- in code inspections everything is set to default, especially unresolved references are set to give a warining.
- turning pycharm off and on again

I appreciate any help

Comment: Try `File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart`. That'll cause it to redo the indexing. Also make sure it isn't in the process of indexing, since it won't show anything during that time.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it didn't work, it still looks the same

Comment: And there's no ongoing tasks shown in the middle of the bottom toolbar?

Comment: @Carcigenicate there's nothing going on only a warning "Windows Defender might be impacting your build performance. PyCharm checked the following directories:
    C:\Users\elias\PycharmProjects\Chess
    C:\Users\elias\.PyCharmCE2019.3\system
    C:\Users\elias\.gradle

But I already fixed this before and nothing happened.

Comment: It seems like my code doesn't get interpreted and checked for errors "on the fly" but only when I click run. The only thing marked in the editor are syntax errors.

Comment: If you do `Code -> Inspect Code`, does it list anything?

Comment: @Carcigenicate "No suspicious code found. 0 files processed in 'Project 'Chess''."
apparantly it doesn't inspect my files - what should I do?

EDIT:
I fixed it - the files were excluded, I right clicked them and unmarked as exclueded. Thanks for the hint now it works!

Comment: What happens on right-clicking on `foofill` and choosing `Go To - Declaration or Usages`?

Comment: @user2235698 I solved the issue now. See my comment above.  Thus, if I chose Go To - Declaration or Usages now it would behave normally. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @EliasM. you should post a self-answer with the solution and accept the answer. Future readers will benefit more from it than seeing a zero-answer question in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it - the files were excluded, I right clicked them and unmarked as exclueded.
Then I invalidated caches and restarted.
Thanks for the hints everyone.